What does the encounter with Lizaveta in Part 1 Chapter 5 of Crime and Punishment mean?
In this chapter after having his dream, Raskolnikov seemed to abandon his murder plan for his conscience started to awake, and he even prayed to God. But why did Dostoevsky made Raskolnikov to overhear Lizaveta immediately after this so that he knew he had the perfect opportunity for his murder? Is this pre-deterministic fate? Does it go against free will? To me this doesn’t seem like God’s work, could it be that it was Satan’s work? I know that Dostoevsky was a devout Christian, so what was the idea behind this design of the story? Thanks!

You have unknowingly touched on the main theme of the book.  That main theme is two-fold. The first one is: Person's thoughts don't matter, their actions do. The second one is: Opportunity makes a thief. Raskolnikov has all sorts of thoughts and rationalizations, both for the murder and against it. Yet, when the "perfect" opportunity presented itself, what did he choose to do?
He committed murder. All those ideas that he is a good person, that he is above others, that he would use the money better than the current owner... All those don't matter. His actions do and his actions are vile. He was put to the test and he failed. Satan was originally God's prosecutor, he tested humanity FOR God. Raskolnikov had a choice and he chose wrong.
